# FileA has n rows, each row is used to filter rows in FileB in unix

Tags: bash, unix

I have two csv files

FileA

```
ID
1
2
3
```

FileB

```
name,ID
a,1
a,2
a,4
ab,1
ac,1
bb,3
bd,2
ad,2
```

What I want to do is to get each value in FileA and compare whether ID in FileB is equal to ID in FileA, if matched, print the entire row in FiLeB and save everything in FileC. Note that the order in FileC is not important

Expected Outcome

FileC

```
name,ID
a,1
a,2
ab,1
ac,1
bb,3
bd,2
ad,2
```

My current rough idea:

```
while read line
do
   helper_function line
done < FileA

helper_function(){
awk -F, '$2==line {print $0}' FileB
... need to implement more...
}
```

But both FileA and FileB are considerably large, I am not sure whether using for loop here is a good idea since it would be time-consuming. Do we have other ways to solve this? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F ',' 'NR==FNR { a[$1]=$1; next}; $2 in a {print $0};' FileA FileB
```

You can change $2 into $4 for matching field 4.
With `grep` you shouldn't use `grep -f FileA FileB` but

```
grep -f <(sed 's/.*/,&$/' FileA) FileB
```

The second grep makes sure you will skip the line `dontwantthis,123456789`.

The sed command will soon grow out-of-control, when you want to add more conditions (the third field,...).

Comment: Hi, what if in my real file, the ID in FileB is column 4, do I just need to chane $2 to $4?

Comment: OP would need the header part also in the final output file I guess.

Comment: @Inian that is true, but it's okay. I can merge the header file to this output. but somehow, the code does not work properly for me...